# toLowerCase() returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm with an weird problem here.
I have a code like this:

```
for (var j = events.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var evtName = events[j].name.toLowerCase();
    //Do something um evtName
}
```

The `events` is an array with JSON objects.

The problem is that sometimes the evtName is set as undefined and I don't know why. I tried to put `console.log(events[j].name + ' - ' + evtName);` and the output is:

```
ENSAIO ABERTO - undefined
PERCUSSÃO TRADICIONAL PORTUGUESA - undefined 
VIAGEM À MÚSICA ANTIGA[CONCERTOS PARA TODOS] - undefined
A MÚSICA TOMA CONTA DE MIM - undefined
NOVIDADES SINFÓNICAS - undefined
OPTIMUS CLUBBING | THE PAINS OF BEING PURE AT HEART | SEBASTIAN DJ - undefined
ENSAIO ABERTO - undefined
DE GOUNOD A RAVEL - undefined 
ORQUESTRA SINFÓNICA DA ESMAE - undefined 
MÚSICA DE BOLSO[WORKSHOPS PRIMEIROS SONS] - undefined 
MISSÃO EM-POSSÍVEL [MÚSICA EM FAMÍLIA] - missão em-possível [música em família]
ENSAIO ABERTO - ensaio aberto 
CRIOLO - criolo 
OPTIMUS CLUBBING | SUPERNADA | THE MAGICIAN | JORI HULKKONEN - optimus clubbing |    supernada | the magician | jori hulkkonen
```

And I know that the problem is at the atribution `var evtName = events[j].name.toLowerCase();` because if I put `console.log(events[j].name + ' - ' + events[j].name.toLowerCase());` the string is corrected 'lower cased'.

I tried to put `toString()` in the atribution, didn't work too.

I need to have it in a variable because I need to format it more (like put the initial letters in capital, etc).

Any help? Thanks in advance

Found it. It was a missing '{'. The console didn't alert it though... Im really sorry for taking your time guys, thanks for all who helped

Comment: Looks like it's happening when you have diacritics in your string.

Comment: Can you somehow reproduce the problem with a snippet of code on jsFiddle?

Comment: Could you post the JSON data itself? And could you tell us _where_ you logged the name and evtName? right after the `toLowerCase()` call, or is there some code in between that _might_ muddle up the `evtName` value, and that includes functions, of course

Comment: Please provide the complete code which produced your sample output and also the data array.

Comment: @CyberDude: but some of the undefined don't have them...

Comment: Is there a reason you're repeating the `var` declaration inside your loop?

Comment: @ScottSauyet indeed `ENSAIO ABERTO` appears twice and they have different outcomes :)

Comment: can't reproduce the problem...

Comment: can't reproduce - http://jsfiddle.net/aAyB8/

Comment: Can't duplicate it either: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/S3hjA/

Comment: The only way `toLowerCase()` will return `"undefined"` is if it's called on a string `"undefined"` *(using any combination of upper/lower case characters of course)*. There's a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: ...also, `undefined` isn't a valid JSON value, but the string `"undefined"` is of course. So either your JSON is storing  the string `"undefined"` as the `name` value, or you're doing some post-processing that you're not showing here, or you aren't actually using JSON data.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce it in JS fiddle but I have never user it so it didnt work =p. 
So, to explain more I will add the whole code that matters up there

Comment: Im really sorry guys... It was just a '{' missing... Sorry for taking you time, and thanks very much =/

Comment: The problem was the console did not warn anything because I missed a { and a }... So it was "right"... =s